\node_modules\expo-router\entry.js ERROR Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child
I'm following an Expo React Native tutorial and have made several changes across different files (trying to implement Clerk authentication) since it last worked.
Now, when I run npx expo start, I get the following error:
iOS Bundled 10340ms C:\UberClone\node_modules\expo-router\entry.js (1274 modules)
 ERROR  Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

I've tried undoing all the changes I can remember, and I also ran the command npm install --save-dev babel-preset-expo which I found while searching for a solution online.
The error message only points to the entry.js file, which I haven’t modified or even opened.
Could this problem be caused by something in my code, or is it more likely related to something else?

There is something wrong with the code, instead of passing a JSX element you are passing function somewhere, share your file which is causing this error.

@sphnx Yes, the error message is quite self-explanatory, and I have already searched on Google about it. The problem is that it doesn't specify where the error is located (file and line), and I have modified 6 files and added a few new ones since it last worked properly.

Well, the way to debug would be to open your router file and check if the last page you added was added correctly. (I guess this error came because you created a screen and used it in the expo router file, like creating a route for which a mapping doesn't exist in the pages/ app folder)

Thank you so much for your help @sphnx you were right about the bug's location — it was within the return statement of the Expo router file.

@sphnx was right to suggest starting the debugging process by exploring the Expo router file. That was exactly where the bug was — a function within the return value.

Many thanks to him for taking the time to help me!
